# adviceexecution() is not working in AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm learning Java and somehow I got into AspectJ. I tried to execute this code from tutorial book:

```
    pointcut adviceExecutionPointcut( ) : adviceexecution( );

   // Advice declaration
   before( ) : adviceExecutionPointcut( )
      && !within(AdviceExecutionRecipe +)
   {
      System.out.println(
         "------------------- Aspect Advice Logic --------------------");
      System.out.println("In the advice picked by ExecutionRecipe");
      System.out.println(
         "Signature: "
            + thisJoinPoint.getStaticPart( ).getSignature( ));
      System.out.println(
         "Source Line: "
            + thisJoinPoint.getStaticPart( ).getSourceLocation( ));
      System.out.println(
         "------------------------------------------------------------");
   }
}
```

And it somehow gave me an error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at helloWorld.ajc$before$helloWorld$2$5e65e204(helloWorld.aj)
    at helloWorld.ajc$before$helloWorld$2$5e65e204(helloWorld.aj)
    at helloWorld.ajc$before$helloWorld$2$5e65e204(helloWorld.aj)
    at helloWorld.ajc$before$helloWorld$2$5e65e204(helloWorld.aj)
    at helloWorld.ajc$before$helloWorld$2$5e65e204(helloWorld.aj)
```

For reference this is the example code and the advice code.

```
public class myClass {

    public void foo(int number, String name){
        System.out.println("Inside foo(int, String)");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myClass myObject = new myClass();
    myObject.foo(1, "ican");

    }


public aspect helloWorld {
    public int a;
    long startTime;


    pointcut callPointcut(int value, String name) :
        call(* myClass.foo(int, String)) && args(value,name);

     before(int value, String name) : callPointcut(value,name)
       {
         startTime = System.nanoTime();
          System.out.println("Start Time in ns :" + startTime);
       }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what's the error? does it even compile? paste in your stack trace maybe

Comment: It doesn't compile. It's put in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the type declaration for the aspect containing the adviceexecution pointcut? I suspect you dropped that advice block into your `helloWorld` aspect. The reason you are getting the recursive stackoverflow is because the advice is applying to itself. The guard `!within(AdviceExecutionRecipe +)` is meant to stop the advice applying to itself. However, you can't just change that from `AdviceExecutionRecipe` to `helloWorld` because then it won't apply to any of your advice. So I would keep that advice block in a separate aspect and call it `AdviceExecutionRecipe`.  With that in place, it works for me:

```
$ ajc -1.8 *.java -showWeaveInfo

Join point 'adviceexecution(void helloWorld.ajc$before$helloWorld$1$68d3c671(int, java.lang.String))' in Type 'helloWorld' (helloWorld.java:9) advised by before advice from 'AdviceExecutionRecipe' (AdviceExecutionRecipe.java:5)

Join point 'method-call(void myClass.foo(int, java.lang.String))' in Type 'myClass' (myClass.java:10) advised by before advice from 'helloWorld' (helloWorld.java:9)

$ java myClass

------------------- Aspect Advice Logic --------------------
In the advice picked by ExecutionRecipe
Signature: void helloWorld.before(int, String)
Source Line: helloWorld.java:9
------------------------------------------------------------
Start Time in ns :216368803494701
Inside foo(int, String)
```